# su not working when non-root (authentification failure)

Tags: linux, passwords, authentication, su

On a VPS I own (hosted at bluevm.com), I have three users:

- `userone`, with password `foo`, and sudo rights.
- `usertwo`, with password `bar`, without sudo rights.
- `root`, with now password (deleted with `passwd -d`)

**I can't use `su` when non-root to swicth from `userone` to `usertwo` and vice-versa**, although I'm sure the password is OK since I use it to connect via ssh, and the keyboard layout seems to be OK. Also, the `passwd` command does not seem to work.

### When connecting as userone

`ssh` to connect works:

```
$ ssh userone@example.com
userone@example.com's password: foo
Last login: blah blah
```

`su otheruser` does not work:

```
$ su usertwo
Password: bar
su: Authentication failure
```

self-`su` does not work:

```
$ su userone
Password: foo
su: Authentication failure
```

`ssh otheruser@localhost` works:

```
ssh usertwo@localhost
usertwo@localhost's password: 
Last login: blah blah
$ who am i
usertwo blah blah
$ exit
```

`passwd` does not work:

```
$ passwd
Changing password for userone.
(current) UNIX password: foo
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

`sudo` works, and when root `su otheruser` works:

```
$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for userone: foo
# su usertwo
$ who am i
usertwo blah blah
$ exit
$ exit
```

### When connecting as usertwo

`ssh` to connect works:

```
$ ssh usertwo@example.com
usertwo@example.com's password: bar
Last login: blah blah
```

`su otheruser` does not work:

```
$ su userone
Password: foo
su: Authentication failure
```

self-`su` does not work:

```
$ su usertwo
Password: bar
su: Authentication failure
```

`passwd` does not work:

```
$ passwd
Changing password for usertwo.
(current) UNIX password: bar
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

Comment: Does /var/log/auth.log get any additional info about the su authentication failure?

Comment: You can use `sudo  su - newuser`

Comment: @Hennes No, not when I'm logged in as usertwo, which does not have sudo rights.

Comment: @circle when `usertwo` runs `su userone`, in `/var/log/auth.log` I have `su[25796]: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname=usertwo uid=1002 euid=1002 tty=/dev/pts/4 ruser=usertwo rhost=  user=userone`, then `pam_authenticate: Authentication failure`, then `FAILED su for userone by usertwo`, then `- /dev/pts/4 usertwo:userone`.

Answer (score 1):

Some UNIX:es requires you to be member of the `wheel` group to be able to switch user.
from [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_%28Unix%29):

```
Some Unix-like systems have a wheel group of users, and only allow these users 
to su to root.[1]
This may or may not mitigate these security concerns, since an intruder might
first simply break into one of those accounts.
```

Check weather your `otheruser` are a member, and maybe compare `id userone` with `id usertwo` and see if maybe userone is a member of groups which usertwo are not, granting extra privileges.

Comment: Interesting insight. I tried adding both users to the same list of groups, but without success (also, I can't `su` from `userone` to `userone ` itself). The system does not have a `wheel` group (it is a `Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.7 (squeeze)` system), but I'll try to investigate that idea further.